# Changing xaml code position based on screen size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Basically, I have a lot of xaml code that uses margins, and is base on the 1366x768 screen size. Unfortunately, my monitor is 1920x1080, so when it launches, my UI seems a little bit squished and the data is pushed to the wrong place. Is there a way to make my program launch in 1366x768 and not be allowed to change screen size?

Also maybe, if I do go 1080p, it still looks good - like, some of my ui elements just move across the page, and all my combo boxes just get huge

Does this all make sense? If not, just say :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, all you need to do is set the "ResizeMode" property of the Window:

```
 <Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
 ....
 Title="MainWindow"
 ResizeMode="NoResize"
 Height="1366" Width="768">
```

Regarding the second part of your question. I have a feeling that perhaps you're not quite using the available ways to lay out controls in WPF properly. UI Elements shouldn't move across the screen if you use Grids, DockPanels, and StackPanels to lay out your controls. I'd recommend you look at some examples. Post your XAML if you want a more specific suggestion regarding this :).